# Deploying nodejs in our own server

Tags: node.js, web-services, deployment, web-deployment

I am new to nodejs. I've created a simple webservice and it works on local but by using node app/nodemon app. Well I want to publish it internet and deploy my service in our server.  (We do not want to use external servers/services such as heroku, azure etc.)

As I searched, peopel mostly deployed those services. So what is the best way to deploy a WS with nodejs in your own server?

I have a windows server for now but would like to use may be in linux platform later.

Comment: Without much more info (do you guys use dedicated VMs? Containers? Or just one big box running services), it's hard to recommend something. You could look into pm2, which is basically hypervisor tailored to Node.js

Comment: I would suggest a Linux server. There are few things you need to be careful - 1) Use pm2 for starting the server 2) Use pm2-log package as well very simple only need to install it globally 3) Use cluster mode pm2 provide this option and it's very easy only some new arguments needed to be added. 4) If you go with Linux will suggest you add swap memory as well. Awesome tutorials are available about this on digital ocean blogs. If need help please free to contact would help you through the process.

Comment: @Sander  thank you for the answer. I think that np2 is what i am looking for. I've watched several videos and it look great, brings many advantages.. Thank you for the replies

Comment: @RohitDalal the message above is also for you but could not mentioned 2 people in one message. But I have a specific question for you. You said there is a documentation on digitalocean. Do I have to use digitalocean or using linux is enough? Probably we will use windows server but other developers can host in linux environment

Comment: I meant Digital ocean Blogs Site - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04.
You only need a server and ssh access to it and you will be able to deploy the server.

Comment: I recently recorded a screencast about how to deploy Nod.ejs app on ubuntu - maybe it would help you somehow: https://youtu.be/8PpBySjkWEM